# CS50: For Loop Design

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50, strlen

Currently doing the CS50 lectures, and in week 2, starting at about 56:45 on this video (https://video.cs50.net/2016/fall/lectures/2?t=56m50s) he mentions that the `strlen` function should be moved into the initialized variable section of the `for` loop, rather than stay in the conditions section, because leaving it in the conditions section makes the computer run the `strlen` function each time the `for` loop increments.

Ok, I get that, but the proposed solution -- to move it into the variable declaration section, doesn't solve the problem, does it? Because it's still in the `for` loop, it looks like the `strlen` function is still being checked each time the `for` loop iterates.

Am I wrong?

Comment: It's probably just how it's being presented (I haven't watched the video, so I can't comment further). But basically:  in the initialisation portion, it's run once, because you only initialise once (at the beginning, to set the variable states at the start of the loop). Leaving it in the condition will call it each iteration, because you have to check the condition (to know if you still with within the condition) at each iteration.

Comment: It is much better to write `for (int len = strlen(str), i = 0; i < len; i++)` than to write `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)`.  The initialization section of the `for` loop is executed just once — not on every iteration.  (We can debate about `int` vs `size_t` and similar issues.  I'd often write the call to `strlen()` outside the the loop altogether.)

Comment: Thanks AntonH and Jonathan. Just to follow up, what is the `int` vs `size_t` debate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 'initialize' section of a 'for()` loop is only run once.

The 'conditional' section of a `for()` loop is run at the beginning of each loop iteration.

The 'step' section of a `for()` loop is run at the end of each loop iteration.

This is why repetitive operations, like a call to `strlen()` should be moved to the initialization section (where is should be setting a local variable)

Comment: Thank you. Is there any difference (stylistically, design-wise, etc.) to place the `strlen` call outside of (before) the `for` loop and assign it to a variable, then reference that variable in the `for` loop (assuming that variable would be used elsewhere, not just the one `for` loop)?

Comment: when writing code, the writer should always strive for readability.
For this reason, *I* would place the call to `strlen()` before the `for()` loop, but either method works.

Answer (score 1):

well,strlen  function will not be called every time in the for loop because we stored the value of strlen before the for loop,
it will look something like this

```
`int n= strlen(s);
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 { 
     code
  }
```

`

once the value of strlen is stored in n ,computer just have to access n rather than accessing strlen again  and again from the string.h library
Hope this answer helps :)